# How to get row count in Razor View

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a two tables join together and return search results view. The record from the query is as below format:

```
degreeid schoolid  seqno  coursename
1        1         1           A
1        1         1           B
1        1         2           C
1        1         3           D
```

I need to count the courses with the same seqno. How do I achieve it in the razor view foreach loop or from the controller? I can create a function to return the count in the controller but how to call this count function from the razor view?

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CourseDataModel db = new CourseDataModel();

    ActionResult Index()
    {
     using (CourseDataModel db = new CourseDataModel())
        {

      var searchResults = (from a in TableA
                           join b in TableB on
                                        new { subject=a.subject, catalog=a.catalog } equals
                                         new { subject=b.Subject, catalog=b.Catalogno } into ab


                                         orderby a.seqno
                                         from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                         select new JoinModel
                                         {
                                             Courselist = a,
                                             Contentsummary = b
                                         }
                                       ).ToList();




                    if (searchResults == null) { return Content("No record found"); }


                            return View(searchResults);

                }
            }
```

My index.cshtml code as below:

```
   @model IEnumerable<course.Models.JoinModel>
             @if (Model != null)
        {

            if (Model.Count() != 0)
            {


                    <table >
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <th class="column1" scope="col">Degree ID</th>
                            <th class="column2" scope="col">Course</th>
                            <th class="column3" scope="col">Count</th>


                        </tr>


                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <!-- display class="new-sequence" when degree_seqno changes-->
                            <tr >
                                <td class="column1">

                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Courselist.degreeno)

                                </td>
                                <td class="column2">
                                              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Courselist.coursename)
                                </td>
                                <td> @* here I want to display a count of the same seqno *@
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                         } 
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.seqno)) 
{
     foreach (var item in group) 
     {
       <tr>
            <td class="column1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.degreeno)
            </td>
            <td class="column2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coursename)
            </td>
            <td>
                @group.Count()
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
}`

Answer (score 0):

How about you group by `seqno` then you can count the results in each `IGrouping`

`group ab by ab.seqno into seqNoGrps`

Then in your view iterate each group

```
@foreach(var grp in Model)
{
    <tr><td>@grp.Key</td></tr>
    @foreach(var joinModel in grp)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Courselist.degreeno)
            </td>
            <td class="column2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Courselist.coursename)
            </td>
            <td> @* here I want to display a count of the same seqno *@
                @grp.Count()
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me where the group by statement should be in linq query?  I am trying to group by but always has red syntax line error in the linq searchResults. Thanks.